# Authenticate user from Perl against Windows local users

Tags: windows, perl, windows-authentication, authentication, windows-users

I need to write a script in Perl under Windows that will receive a username and a password. The script should authenticate the user against the user accounts in that machine, and also, it needs to check if the user belongs to the Administrators group. The server is not on any domain and doesn't have Active Directory, just local accounts.

I've been searching for a Perl solution but all I can find is about connecting to LDAP services. I also searched for ways to authenticate a user from command line but I couldn't find something that works for this case. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong words.

I'd like to know if any of you can think of a way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for any comments! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a way to accomplish this. I'd still like to hear from you guys to see if there's a better method.

Active State Perl includes a module called `Win32::UserAuthentication`, which is *not documented* (and is not on CPAN) and contains a warning about it not being maintained. However, it works over XS and returns a boolean when authenticating a local user. So far it works pretty well and fast for that part.

For the checking of groups the user belongs to, I'm using this system command:

```
net user $user | grep Administrators
```

Which works pretty fast too and so far works for this purpose.

**NOTE: For anyone trying the command above, I only have `grep` because it's on my system path thanks to having `Cygwin` installed.**

If a better solution if proposed, I'll select it as best answer.

Thank you,

Francisco

Comment: You may use the built in function `AuthenticateUser($domain, $user, $pw);`

Comment: Built in where? If you mean Perl, that's exactly what I'm using through the module `Win32::UserAuthentication`, which is not built in, is just a function exported by that module. The thing is, as I said, the module is not on CPAN, is ActivePerl exclusive (although I just copied it to my self-built Perl without issues), is not documented and is not maintained.

Comment: Yes, I meant function from the module. Yes I could not find any other documentation on this module either.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3A%3ANetAdmin should help with the "is an Administrator" part. No idea on non-domain auth though.